# php make posts safe

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, code-injection

I am having trouble with the simplest of tasks.
The html page has a single textarea tag that sends the data to a php file using $.get() with jquery

From there I use a variety of methods from htmlspecialchars to addslashes.
But nothing seems to work the way it should, either throwing off an error because a single \ was left behind or not preserving newlines.

How can I pass a textarea's value to a php file, make it injection proof and json compatible.
So that when I access it with mysql and format it using $.formatJSON(). It works without any issues and preserves all the new line characters?

```
//php

$result = htmlspecialchars($_GET["message"]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (message) VALUES ($result)");


//jquery
$.ajax({
 url:("http://websitename.com/post.php?message=" + message + "&callback=?"),
 dataType: 'JSONP',
 success:function(json){
    callback($.parseJSON(json));
 },
 error:function(){
 },
});
```

Comment: If this is your actual code, your SQL is wrong. You need to add single quotes to the string you are trying to insert. `mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (message) VALUES (` **'** `$result` **'** `)");` and also escape the string before inserting.

Comment: Thats the point, being able to escape the troublesome characters while retaining the correct ones. Also the php code is just an example.

Comment: May I recommend [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended practice nowadays is to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). This way SQL injections are out of the question. If this proves to be too slow after profiling the code, you should resort to using mysql_(real_)escape_string.

As another step of security you can install an Intrusion Detection System like [PHPIDS](https://phpids.org/) to add another security layer.

Don't use addslashes or similar, they are not meant for escaping user input for SQL queries.

Also in your case you should not pass the textarea contents via GET but rather via POST as described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Furthermore, the dataType should be 'json' and you don't need to parse it afterwards. An example for getting JSON from PHP in jQuery is given [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-6).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend phpids or something similar. All they can do is just to **guess** if request *looks like potentially evil*. So thinking you're safe you can get huge vulnerability, or false alarms. Writing carefully, using prepared statements is not that hard. +1 though

Answer (score 2):

Before using a value in a MySQL query, use `mysql_real_escape_string`. In addition, you should put single quotes around `$result` in `($result)`.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'd appreciate it if the reason for my post's lack of usefulness was explained in a comment.